Getting 504 Error When Project Launched to Deployment
I am having an issue when I launch my Next.js project to deployment. On the development platform I am essentially making a call from a text prompt to an API, which originally called the OpenAI platform (but I have since stripped away the OpenAI code, replacing it with a simple console.log, but the issue persists!). Here is my code in the page.tsx:
const handleSubmission = async () => {
    setMessages((currentMessages) => [
      ...currentMessages,
      {
        id: generateId(),
        role: english.userRole,
        text: input,
        gui: null,
      },
    ]);

    try {
      const response = await submitMessage(input);

      setMessages((currentMessages) => [...currentMessages, response]);
      setInput("");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(english.errors.submittingPrompt, err);
    }
  };

Once the submitMessage function (located in the same folder in file called action.tsx) is called, it calls the following function:
const ASSISTANT_ID = `${process.env.OPENAI_ASSISTANT_ID}`;
let THREAD_ID = "";
let RUN_ID = "";

export async function submitMessage(question: string): Promise<ClientMessage> {
  const statusUIStream = createStreamableUI(english.assistantRole);
  const textStream = createStreamableValue("");
  const textUIStream = createStreamableUI(
    <Message textStream={textStream.value} />
  );

  const runQueue = [];

  (async () => {
    console.log("HI")

    statusUIStream.done();
    textStream.done();
  })();

  return {
    id: generateId(),
    role: english.assistantRole,
    text: textUIStream.value,
  };
}

However, this function calls out every single time, breaching the 15 second time limit. The original calls to OpenAI never took longer than a second or so, and even after stripping most of the code out, I am confused as to why the call to this function is taking so long. Any help as to why this may be the case would be greatly appreciated!
Best,
Adam
I have tried stripping out all of the calls to the OpenAI SDK to see if this is where the issue was. However, even when I have a simple console.log(), it still times out. I also just increased the Serverless functions time limit on Vercel to 1 minute and it still time outs.
